# Шаблон функции с непонятным аргументом

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++, метапрограммирование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую роль здесь играет `class = std::string`? Если `убрать`/`оставить`, то поменяется ли что-то ?

```
template<class T, class = std::string>
void fun(T var) {
    std::cout << "Hello " << var << std::endl;
}
```

p.s. Вопрос задаю исходя из непонятного синтаксиса с `std::enable_if_t`, когда мы в шаблоне пишем похожую строку

Comment: Ну добейте кто-нибудь ещё один голос, чтобы переоткрыть! А товарищ @user7860670, расскажите, где в вашем оригинале содержится ответ?

Comment: @maestro ¿А что вас смущает? ОП же написал *"задаю исходя из непонятного синтаксиса с std::enable_if_t, когда мы в шаблоне пишем похожую строку"* - а дубликате как раз рассказывается про SFINAE и синтаксис использования enable_if.

Comment: *"какую роль здесь играет"* Никакую не играет, его можно убрать без изменения поведения. Вам помог такой ответ? Что-то я подозреваю, что не помог. *"задаю исходя из непонятного синтаксиса с `std::enable_if_t`"* Спрашивайте сразу про тот синтаксис, который вам на самом деле интересен.